# ROS robot operating system advanced combat

Tags: python, ros

The courses include Topic communication, Service communication, ROS custom message, URDF visualization, TF coordinate transformation and other technical essentials. Each technical point will explain the principle clearly with examples. In order to achieve the purpose of applying what we have learned, we will carry out knowledge expansion and realize the corresponding vivid and interesting requirements for each technical point, so as to ensure that we will have a great harvest after learning.

Comment: https://www.lanqiao.cn/courses/2947

Comment: This is a spam post!